# firebase deploy error when site attribute is not specified in firebase.json

Tags: firebase, deployment, firebase-hosting

I'm using firebase hosting and when I try to deploy my project, I get the following error:

[image]

The firebase log says the following:

*[debug] [2020-05-03T14:31:51.377Z] TypeError: Cannot read property 'deploys' of undefined
    at C:\Users\albert.valeta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\index.js:84:36
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)*

The command I'm using is:

firebase deploy --only hosting:last-call-manager-pre

The firebase.json is:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The weird thing is that when I add the *site* property to the firebase.json is doesn't throw any error and completes the deploy. That firebase.json looks like:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "site": "last-call-manager-pre",
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I care about the error because I have 2 different environments and I don't want to modify the firebase.json file everytime I want to deploy for each targetted environment. Besides, I don't know exactly the meaning of this site attribite and didn't found too much information about it.

Could someone help me solve this issue?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm in the same situation. No documentation whatsoever on this

Comment: Still in the same situation @Spock. 

Comment: I figured it out, @Albert -it's late now but I'll see if I can boil it down and write later

Comment: Hi @Spock, that's good news!! Let me know when you can how to fix that.

Comment: posted something now - let me know if you have questions

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have a project where I have 2 environments ( test + prod) that are located in 2 different Firebase projects. Each firebase project contains multiple apps so I also need to specify which app to deploy to, in each project.

```
Firebase project name for test is "firebase-app-test"
Firebase project name for prod is "firebase-app-prod"
App name in the test Firebase project is "app-test"
App name in the prod Firebase project is "app-prod"
```

firebase.json looks like this:

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
    "target": "test",
    "public": "dist",
    ... rest of settings for test project
    },
   { 
    "target": "production",
    "public": "dist",
    ... rest of settings for prod project
   }
 ]
}
```

.firebaserc then looks like:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "firebase-project-test",
    "test": "firebase-project-test",
    "production": "firebase-project-prod"
  },
  "targets": {
    "firebase-project-prod": {
      "hosting": {
        "production": [
          "app-prod"  
        ]
      }
    },
    "firebase-project-test": {
      "hosting": {
        "test": [
          "app-test"
        ]
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Deploy the test app to the firebase-project-test:

```
firebase deploy --only hosting:test --project test
```

Deploy the prod app to the firebase-project-prod

```
firebase deploy --only hosting:production --project production
```